# Why do the prefixes and suffixes of certain Java currency formats end with a space-like character instead of space?

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I'm retrieving all available Java currency formats as follows:

```
for(Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    for(Currency currency : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()) {
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        numberFormat.setCurrency(currency);
        //do something with the format
    }
}
```

I was trying to parse string like `EUR 5` when I noticed that there is a format which is a `DecimalFormat` (they all are) with the `positivePrefix` `EUR` however the last character is not space, but one with the numeric value `-1`. And this prefix never matches `EUR` (with a real space) in `EUR 5` which makes it useless for an important use case.

I can work around the problem by creating my own `DecimalFormat`s, however I'd like to understand why I'm getting these formats, i.e. prefixes in the formats, and whether there's may be a configuration option I'm missing in order to avoid them (and get "real" spaces for the formats with a trailing or leading space in the prefix or suffix).

Did I hit a bug?

I did the following verification:

```
boolean positivePrefixTrailingSpace = false;
boolean positiveSuffixLeadingSpace = false;
boolean negativePrefixTrailingSpace = false;
boolean negativeSuffixLeadingSpace = false;
for(Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    for(Currency currency : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()) {
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        numberFormat.setCurrency(currency);
        DecimalFormat numberFormatCast = (DecimalFormat)numberFormat;
        if(numberFormatCast.getPositivePrefix().endsWith(" ")
                && numberFormatCast.getPositivePrefix().contains("EUR")) {
            positivePrefixTrailingSpace = true;
        }
        if(numberFormatCast.getPositiveSuffix().startsWith(" ")
                && numberFormatCast.getPositivePrefix().contains("EUR")) {
            positiveSuffixLeadingSpace = true;
        }
        if(numberFormatCast.getNegativePrefix().endsWith(" ")
                && numberFormatCast.getPositivePrefix().contains("EUR")) {
            negativePrefixTrailingSpace = true;
        }
        if(numberFormatCast.getNegativeSuffix().startsWith(" ")
                && numberFormatCast.getPositivePrefix().contains("EUR")) {
            negativeSuffixLeadingSpace = true;
        }
    }
}
```

in which all booleans are `false`.

I'm looking for `NumberFormat`s/`DecimalFormat`s with space in their prefix or suffix because I'm working with OCR data which will hardly ever have a protected (=non-line-breaking) space.

I'm using OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 18.10 with german default locale/language pack (which shouldn't have any influence on the code above afaik).

Comment: Does your probably go away if you search for any whitespace `\\s+` intead of `' '`?

Comment: It's most likely because the string `EUR 5` should not be line-wrapped.

Comment: @corsiKa My probably? My problem? I'm not using those prefixes, but `NumberFormat.parse` is and the JRE provides them. I can only manipulate the values returned by it. And I'm looking for a way to avoid that (configuration, etc.).

Comment: @chrylis Ahh... that makes sense. However, it doesn't make sense that there's only one `NumberFormat` returned. It seems odd that prefixes (and suffixes) of `DecimalFormat`s provided by the JRE are literals rather than regular expressions. Or otherwise the returned value should contain an instance for each whitespace character for both prefix and suffix and both positive and negative - which would be a waste in comparison of REs.